# AngularJS animating basic ng-repeat slider

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Essentially is there a simple way to leverage the `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` hooks on the `ng-repeat` directive to animate a basic slider left and right?

You can see the **[plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O75ciBaWdzcuCqfgsTD4?p=preview)** which is almost working.

I have a basic slider that transitions through a list of elements one page at a time using a partition filter and `ng-repeat`. This works as expected except when you switch directions, in which case the `ng-leave` transition on the previous direction is run causing a erroneous result.

I could write a custom slider directive or even use the angular-ui carousel but I don't want to over-complicate such a simple example if indeed a simple solution does exist. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This screenshot shows the problem, and points to the solution.

[image: angular-animate.js]

The element passed to the animation leave function has the old class value.

Oddly, I have not been able to replicate this screenshot because the `$scope` mysteriously became unavailable. `$rootScope` is always available though. But it does seem you could do this without injecting `$rootScope`.

My solution is this:

Decorate the `$animate.leave` function like this:

```
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$animate", function ($delegate, $rootScope) {
        $delegate.originalLeave = $delegate.leave;
        $delegate.leave = function (element, doneCallback) {
            // THIS IS THE ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONALITY
            $(element).removeClass("right").removeClass("left").addClass($rootScope.direction);
            $delegate.originalLeave(element, doneCallback);
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
})
```

Then place the `direction` variable on the `$rootScope`, which will of course need to be injected into the controller.

This solution requires jQuery, but it could be easily done without it.

[Here is the working Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/I2vmyTxK2kN3slqCQxFV/preview)

Comment: You are correct, the element passed to the leave function has the old direction value as it is that class (or direction) that is 'leaving' the element. The problem with that solution, however, is that modifying `angular-animate`, a core AngularJS module, could affect other `leave` animations in the app and also mean you could no longer update to new releases without making the same changes. I was hoping for a simple solution, maybe there isn't one.

Comment: We can decorate the $animate service as shown in the new answer. This is pretty normal practice, and will not break anything so long as we are sensible about how the decoration is implemented. Also, a little more work and I'm pretty sure we could do it without $rootScope or jQuery.

Comment: That's a clever way to do it, will start playing with this and see how we go. What seemed such a simple problem has not been easy to solve. If nothing simpler comes to light shortly I will mark as answer, it's a good solution, appreciate the help!

Comment: jQuery Lite implements `addClass` and `removeClass` so no need for jQuery as they are already available on the `element` object. To remove any reference to `$rootScope` might need a simple provider so direction is available in config phase. Is it really that 'bad' to use `$rootScope` in this situation? Cheers again.

Comment: Having an issue, by using a decorator in this way once a direction has been set it will trigger the animation on every element with an `ng-enter` hook (`ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`). Setting a `$timeout` in the decorator for the duration of the animation to unset `$rootScope.direction` works but seem very hacky and could cause issues when multiple animations are triggered in short succession. Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-fx!](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ng-Fx) Documentation and install instruction can be found [here](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ng-Fx)

Here is an example of how it can be used with ng-repeat :

```
<ul ng-controller="FoodController">
  <li class='fx-fade-down fx-speed-800 fx-easing-bounce' ng-repeat="food in foods">
    {{ food }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will use a fx-fade-down effect on the ng-repeated item, in 800 ms, with an 'easing' of bounce.

Additionally "Note that ng-repeat will not trigger animations upon page load, the collection you are iterating over must be empty at first then populated, you can achieve this with a simple timeout or some other async operation" :

```
angular.module('foodApp', ['ngAnimate', 'fx.animations'])
.controller('FoodController', function($scope, $timeout){
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.foods = ['apple', 'muffin', 'chips'];
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: From the documentation I don't see how `ng-fx` can solve this specific problem, it can apply an animation on enter and leave but I need different animations not based on a static class. Would it be possible to modify the Plunk to show what you mean? I was hoping to use only CSS animations and not have to include a GSAP library (I am aware of the advantages though) but happy to consider this if it can be applied, cheers.